# Userform does not populate at initialize code

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am using Excel VBA to create and organize color palettes and gradients using Cell interior color and multiple colorspaces. I am successful in getting the formula and code to get the numeric RGB values of selected cells, but when I try to put those values in a custom Userform, it does not populate for some reason.

Userform in question. The R, G and B textboxes should be populated by 191, 143, 0

[image]

Here is the sub before it runs the userform. It is set up so it will either run a different userform or messagebox depending on how I do my cell selection for gradients.

```
Sub RunColorMixer()
    Dim CellCount As Integer, RowCount As Integer, ColCount As Integer
    Dim ActiveRow As Integer, ActiveCol As Integer
    Dim SelectRow As Integer, SelectCol As Integer
    Dim Orientation As String
    
    'Input Phase
    CellCount = Application.Selection.Cells.Count
    RowCount = Application.Selection.Rows.Count
    ColCount = Application.Selection.Columns.Count
    
    ActiveRow = ActiveCell.Row
    ActiveCol = ActiveCell.Column
    
    SelectRow = Application.Selection.Row
    SelectCol = Application.Selection.Column

    Range("D1").Value = CellCount
    Range("E1").Value = RowCount
    Range("F1").Value = ColCount
    Range("G1").Value = ActiveRow
    Range("H1").Value = ActiveCol
    Range("I1").Value = SelectRow
    Range("J1").Value = SelectCol
    Range("K1").Value = Orientation

    'Determine Orientation
    If CellCount = 1 Then   'Case 1 Single Cell
        ColorpickerSingle.Show
    ElseIf RowCount > 1 And ColCount > 1 Then 'Case 2 Diagonal
        MsgBox "Diagonals not supported! Please keep gradients on 1 row or column only!"
    Else
        ColorpickerGradient.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is the initialize code

```
Private Sub ColorpickerGradient_Initialize()
    Dim CellCount As Integer, RowCount As Integer, ColCount As Integer
    Dim ActiveRow As Integer, ActiveCol As Integer
    Dim SelectRow As Integer, SelectCol As Integer
    Dim Orient As String
        
    Dim ColorValue1 As Variant, ColorValue2 As Variant
        
    'Input Phase
    CellCount = Application.Selection.Cells.Count
    RowCount = Application.Selection.Rows.Count
    ColCount = Application.Selection.Columns.Count
        
    ActiveRow = ActiveCell.Row
    ActiveCol = ActiveCell.Column
        
    SelectRow = Application.Selection.Row
    SelectCol = Application.Selection.Column
    
    'Determine Orientation
    If ActiveRow = SelectRow And ActiveCol = SelectCol Then 'Either Down or Right
        If RowCount > 1 Then    'Case 3 Down
            Orient = "Down"
        Else    'Case 4 Right
            Orient = "Right"
            Orientation.Text = "Right"
        End If
    Else    'Either Up or Left
        If RowCount > 1 Then    'Case 5 Up
            Orient = "Up"
            Orientation.Text = "Up"
        Else    'Case 6 Left
            Orient = "Left"
            Orientation.Text = "Left"
        End If
    End If
            
    'Input Color
    ColorValue1 = ActiveCell.Interior.Color
    Select Case Orientation
        Case "Up"
            ColorValue2 = ActiveCell.Offset(-(CellCount - 1), 0).Interior.Color
        Case "Left"
            ColorValue2 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -(CellCount - 1)).Interior.Color
        Case "Down"
            ColorValue2 = ActiveCell.Offset((CellCount - 1), 0).Interior.Color
        Case "Right"
            ColorValue2 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, (CellCount - 1)).Interior.Color
    End Select
        
    sR1.Value = ColorValue1 Mod 256
    sG1.Value = (ColorValue1 \ 256) Mod 256
    sB1.Value = ColorValue1 \ 65536
                
    sR2.Value = ColorValue2 Mod 256
    sG2.Value = (ColorValue2 \ 256) Mod 256
    sB2.Value = ColorValue2 \ 65536
End Sub
```

I also made sure that I have named my textboxes correctly. It should have at least the R channel textbox filled

[image]

Comment: what happens when you run this?  Any error?

Comment: I see you are using `ActiveCell` Can you put a breakpoint and see that it is the relevant cell? Also debug and check what is the value you are getting for `ActiveCell.Interior.Color`

Comment: @TimWilliams no error message, just that the userform stays blank instead of having the values I want them to have.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks. I did it and it was the relevant cell. I have made sure that the the same code at least will run as a sub and it worked fine. It just so happens that when it comes to ColorpickerGradient.Show line, it shows the Userform but does not start the Initialize Event Sub.

Sorry I still need to find how to upload pics through comments

Comment: When you `Show` the form is it already loaded (but hidden)?  Initialize only runs when the form is first loaded.  And shouldn't it be `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams '''Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()'''

YES THANK YOU! This solves the problem!

Thank you very much!

Comment: @TimWilliams please feel free to close this inquiry or put the answer for your own credit. Again I cannot thank you enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Initialize` event handler method doesn't use the name of the form, so it should be

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
```

and not

```
Private Sub ColorpickerGradient_Initialize()
```